# How to implement bubble overlay for Android and iOS in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I found a flutter dependency called [bubble_overlay 0.1.4](https://pub.dev/packages/bubble_overlay) but it's only for android. I need flutter code working for both Android and iOS.